# how to add same code automatically

Tags: joomla2.5, joomla-k2

am using joomla 2.5 and k2 as a contain manager. i have a google adsense code. i want to this code automatically to the end of every new created k2 article. how can do it?
this is the code :

```
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-5337962148356078";
/* mobile banner */
google_ad_slot = "2022270346";
google_ad_width = 320;
google_ad_height = 50;
//-->
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick one of any number of Google ad modules available in the JED here - http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/ads-a-affiliates/affiliate-systems/google-ads

Once you have installed the module, create an instance then assign it to the menu item that corresponds with the K2 items you want the ads to show up on.